# ExecptionInitializerError in hibernate project

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to save data in database using hibernate but getting severe errors Can anyone please help me? I am using mysql database
 Below is my DTO and DAO classes:
**NOTE**-In the DAO class I am getting object of "SessionFactory" type only once using SessionFactoryUtil.getFactory() method by adding jar file which I created to get only and only one object of SessionFactory using the singleton class "SessionFactoryUtil".

```
        ----------------------------------------------------
         *This is DTO class*

            package com.om.hibernate.dto;

            import java.io.Serializable;

            import javax.persistence.Column;
            import javax.persistence.Entity;
            import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
            import javax.persistence.Id;
            import javax.persistence.Table;

            import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
            @Entity
            @Table(name="army_table")
            public class ArmyDTO  implements Serializable{

                @Id
                //here name attribute is user defined and strategy attribute is predefined 
                @GenericGenerator(name="om",strategy="increment")
                @GeneratedValue(generator="om")
                @Column(name = "armyd_id")
                private int aid;
                @Column(name = "army_country_name")
                private String countryName;
                @Column(name = "army_type")
                private String type;
                @Column(name = "army_no_of_rec")
                private String noOfRec;
                @Column(name = "army_batchno")
                private String batchNo;

                public ArmyDTO() {
                    System.out.println("ArmyDTO created");
                }

                public int getAid() {
                    return aid;
                }

                public void setAid(int aid) {
                    this.aid = aid;
                }

                public String getCountryName() {
                    return countryName;
                }

                public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
                    this.countryName = countryName;
                }

                public String getType() {
                    return type;
                }

                public void setType(String type) {
                    this.type = type;
                }

                public String getNoOfRec() {
                    return noOfRec;
                }

                public void setNoOfRec(String noOfRec) {
                    this.noOfRec = noOfRec;
                }

                public String getBatchNo() {
                    return batchNo;
                }

                public void setBatchNo(String batchNo) {
                    this.batchNo = batchNo;
                }

            }
            ----------------------------
            *This is DAO class*
            package com.om.hibernate.dao;

            import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
            import org.hibernate.Session;
            import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
            import org.hibernate.Transaction;

            import com.om.hibernate.dto.ArmyDTO;
            import com.om.hibernate.util.SessionFactoryUtil;

            public class ArmyDAO {

                //getting object of SessionFactory type
                 SessionFactory factory = SessionFactoryUtil.getFactory();

                public void anythingButSave(ArmyDTO armyDTO) {

                    Session session = factory.openSession();
                    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

                    try {
                        session.save(armyDTO);
                        tx.commit();
                    }
                    catch(HibernateException he) {
                        he.printStackTrace();
                        tx.rollback();
                    }
                    finally {
                        session.close();
                    }
                }



                }
        ---------------------------
        This is the class to get only and only one object of 
       **SessionFactory** type
        package com.om.hibernate.util;

        import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
        import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

        /*This Singleton class is created to get the single object of SessionFactory type, we are creating jar file of this project to make use of SessionFactory type object in hibernate project*/
        public final class SessionFactoryUtil {

            private static SessionFactory factory;

        static{
                System.out.println("Starting to init SF through util jar");
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                configuration.configure();
                 factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

                 //in case of real world project never use System.out.println("");
                 System.out.println("SessionFactory(SF) created through util jar");
              }
            public static SessionFactory getFactory() {
                System.out.println("calling getFactory() from util jar");
                return factory;
            }

            public static void closeFactory() {
                System.out.println("We are closing factory , your codewill not work from now ...msg from util jar");
                factory.close();
            }

        }
    ----------------------------------------------
    ----------------------------------------------
    Below is the error appeared in Console
    ----------------------------------------------
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.om.hibernate.dao.ArmyDAO.<init>(ArmyDAO.java:14)
        at com.om.hibernate.util.SaveTester.main(SaveTester.java:18)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
        at com.om.hibernate.util.SessionFactoryUtil.<clinit>(SessionFactoryUtil.java:15)
        ... 2 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:40)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:19)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:138)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
        ... 16 more
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

    Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2104)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:729)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:283)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
        ... 31 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:276)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2027)
        ... 41 more
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    My hibernate configuration file is:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_db</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password">92*csoni</property>          
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
    -----------------------------------------
    Total jars I am using are:
    1.antlr-3.1.1
    2.dom4j-1.6.1
    3.hibernate-common-annotations..
    4.hibernate-core-5.0.4 Final
    5.hiberante-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0Final
    6.javaee
    7.javaassit-3.17.1-GA
    8.jboss-logging-3.0.0Final
    9.mysql-connector-java-5.1.5-bin
    and one more jar that I created to get SessionFactory type object only once.
```

Comment: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect means that hibernate cannot access the database. Is url, username and password correct?

Comment: yes correct but one issue is when I am seeing the "hibernate.cfg.xml" file in eclipse text editor then some red lines are appearing like errors for non meaningful words appear in microsoft word